# Having different vue configs for different environments

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-cli

I have default vue `.env` configs: `prod.env.js` and `dev.env.js`.

I want to have additional config `prod-debug.env.js` to keep there:

```
NODE_ENV: '"production"',
DEBUG_MODE: true,
//some other variables different from prod and dev config
```

for using on my remote dev server (something like pre-production stage).

I can create that config, but how can I build my app using npm? If I use `npm run build` for building with `prod.env.js`, can I use something like `npm run build --config=prod-debug.env.js`?

---

Update: my `vue-cli` version is 2.9.5.

Comment: You should provide your vue-cli version. If you didn't create your project with vue-cli, you should paste your webpack/browserify whatever config file.